# Slim Framework - Using a GET route

Tags: rest, slim

I'm absolutely new to Slim Framework. I'm working on an Webservice that should provide an interface between an Android App and a Web-Application. I used the Slim Documentation to make my first steps and now I want to create a simple GET route, to receive information from the App. Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$name_outside = '';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/session/program_name/:name', function ($name) use($app) {
    $name_outside = $name;
    echo $name;
});

$app->run(); 

echo $name_outside;
```

I need to access the variable :name outside the function, but what I get is nothing. What I am doing wrong here?

Btw: I know that GET-routes usually are used to list existing resources, but for my simple case, I decided to use it that way.

Comment: Have i solved your problem? If so mark it as answer or tell us something, don't leave the question open

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code to hold name as  args parameters ,then you can get in in Your function

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$name_outside = '';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/session/program_name/{name}', function ($args) use($app) {
    $name_outside = $args['name'];
    echo $args['name'];
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

To acess the `$name_outside` inside the function context you pass it.

`$app->get('/session/program_name/:name', function ($name) use($app, &$name_outside) {
    $name_outside = $name;
    echo $name;
});`

But perhaps you're using Slim in a wrong way. Why you have to access the variable outside of your route?

No code is execyted after the `run()` call. That's the way slim works, try to put a die where you're echo the variable, it isn't reachable.

You shouldn't have the need to access the context of the route outside of it this way. To transform a request or a response you use middlewares with the hooks.

Comment: I was thinking the wrong way. Now I call the Database inside the route, and it works.

Actually I wanted to count incoming data and then, if the expected data is complete, I had inserted it to the database. But now I count everything in the database using Stored Procedures. 

Thanks for help...

Comment: You've to encapsulate all in route function. It receive the request and also handle the output.
Don't forget to mark the answer as solved